# $K[α]$ is isomorphic to a field extension of $K[T]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Here is an exercise I think I managed to solve a part of it.

> Let $A$ be a ring containing a field $K$ an $\alpha \in A$ any element, then the subring $K[\alpha] \subset A$ generated by $K$ and $\alpha$ is isomorphic to $K[T]$ or is a field extension of the form $K[T]/(f)$, where $f$ is irreducible.

**What I managed to do so far:**
I divided the problem into two parts, where $\alpha$ is nilpotent or not. If it is not a nilpotent element, then it is clear to me that $K[\alpha]$ is isomorphic to $K[T]$, my problem is in the other case when $\alpha$ is nilpotent. I set $m$ to be the smallest natural number such that $\alpha^m=0$. Then I thought to choose $f=T^m$. However, then $f$ is not irreducible. I do not know how to overcome this obstacle.

Comment: Where does $T$ come from?

Comment: $T$ denotes here the general variable of a polynomial.

Comment: $T$ is just the independent variable. The book I am using uses this notation instead of $F[x]$.

Comment: There can be *algebraic* elements of $A$ over $K$. Think about e.g. $\Bbb Q[\sqrt2]$..

Comment: If $K$ is the rationals, and $A$ is any ring containing the rationals and $\sqrt2$, then $\sqrt2$ is not nilpotent, but $K[\sqrt2]$ is a field extension, not isomorphic to $K[T]$.

Comment: I see where I made a mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Who says that $f$ has to be irreducible?

**Every ring $K[\alpha]$ generated by a single element over a field is isomorphic to $K[T]/(f)$ where $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ (possibly $0$ if $\alpha$ is transcendental).** So in particular it is not true that $K[\alpha] \cong K[T]$ when $\alpha$ is not nilpotent.

And, *on the other hand*, if $f$ is irreducible then $(f)$ is a prime ideal (since $K[T]$ is a UFD). If $(f)$ is prime then $K[T]/(f)$ is an integral domain and hence has no nilpotents. Thus if $\alpha$ is nilpotent, $K[\alpha]$ will never be isomorphic to $K[T]/(f)$ where $f$ is irreducible.